# My app.get only shows me the first item array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I have a problem with my app.get("/clientes"). It only shows me the first array item (Juan Perez, 18). I think im doing something wrong with for sentence. I dont know if i can use a res.send inside a for sentence, and when I change clientes[3].nombre it shows me different results.

````
const app = express();

clientes = [
    {
        nombre: "Juan",
        apellido: "Perez",
        edad: 18
    },
    {
        nombre: "Hernan",
        apellido: "Dominguez",
        edad: 27
    },
    {
        nombre: "Maria",
        apellido: "Torres",
        edad: 42
    },
    {
        nombre: "Daniela",
        apellido: "Garcia",
        edad: 34
    }
];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("<h1><center>Esta es la ruta principal</h1></center>");
});

app.get('/clientes', function(req, res){
    for(i=0; i<clientes.length; i++){
        res.send("Nombre: "+clientes[i].nombre+", Apellido: "+clientes[i].apellido+", Edad: "+clientes[i].edad+"<br>");
    }
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.send("<h1><center>No se pudo encontrar la pagina indicada, vuelva al <a href='/'>menu</a></center></h1>");


});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Conectado");
});```
````

Comment: Send the whole `clientes` as JSON instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `/clientes` endpoint, you have called `res.send` inside `for` loop so only first item is sent. It is needed to get the whole `send` string first and return that on `res.send`.

```js
app.get('/clientes', function(req, res){
  let clientes = '';
  for(i = 0; i < clientes.length; i ++) {
    clientes += "Nombre: " + clientes[i].nombre + ", Apellido: " + clientes[i].apellido + ", Edad: " + clientes[i].edad + "<br>";
  }

  res.send(clientes);
});
```

Comment: Now it worked, only had to change let clientes to another name. Thank you Derek!